# SQL Server 2008 and .NET Framework 4

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, installation

I've done a search and could not find similar questions.. I have to install SQL Server 2008 Standard on a new server where we need to deploy some .NET 4.0 applications.

My question is: do I need to install .NET 3.5 SP1, then SQL Server 2008 and at the end .NET 4.0? I mean, Is it mandatory to install .NET 3.5 SP1 because SQL Server 2008 cannot work directly with .NET 4.0?

THANKS

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server 2008 cannot work directly with .NET 4.0"?  Are you using SQL CLR?  If not, it should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 requires .NET 3.5 SP1. If you don't already have that installed, install it.

After that, I would move on to installing SQL Server 2008. If you're missing pre-requisites you should install them.

After you get everything straightened out there, I would install .NET 4.0 last (if it's not already on the server). Honestly, though, it shouldn't matter if you install SQL Server 2008 R2 or .NET 4.0. Both orders should work equally as well.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you install .NET Framework 4, sql server installer still ask you to install .NET Framework 3.5. If you install sql server 2008 Standarc in windows server 2008 R2, .NET Framework 3.5 is already built in with windows. Just go to server manager, click Add Feature and enable it. After that, you can install SQL Server 2008.